# How to generate an universal framework(XCFramework) using Microsoft App Center?

Tags: ios, swift, continuous-integration, visual-studio-app-center, xcframework

In our iOS project, we are using custom-run scripts in the project build settings to generate a universal framework.

Right now we are moving toward automation (CI/CD) specifically Visual Studio App Center.

I am able to generate and distribute only an IPA file using the App centre. With some custom build scripts, I am able to add additional values and functionalities post and pre-build. But I haven’t found any way to generate a Framework using the Microsoft App centre build process.

**My question:**
Is there any way that we can generate a universal framework (Ex: XCFramework) from the Microsoft App centre either using custom build scripts or any other methods?

Comment: It's like asking "Can I build XCFramework from command line?" - sure you can: VSAC is just CI/CD, not build system, so it's **running your build process**, it's not creating its own. I.e. it starts a mac (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/software), runs the steps you outlined in your project/workspace scheme, and this is it. It doesn't "generate" anything, your Xcode build does.